# How to parse query syntax into DB query with grouping and precedence?

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, mongodb, data-structures

Suppose, I have string the below string

```
((data eq 3) AND ((d gte 4) OR (f lt 5)))
```

How can someone convert this into below WHERE clause in Node.js/Javascript,

```sql
SELECT * from <table-name> where count = 3 AND ((de >= 4) OR (fr < 5))
```

OR
in MongoDB way,

```js
db.collection.find({
 $and: [
   {data: {$eq: 3}},
   {
     $or: [
       {d: {$gte: 4}},
       {f: {$lt: 5}}
     ]
   }

 ]
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After little bit exploring the data structures, I thought to go with [Binary Expression Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_expression_tree).

These are the steps I have done,

1. Split expression into tokens
2. [Convert the tokens of infix format into postfix format](https://www.free-online-calculator-use.com/infix-to-postfix-converter.html)
3. [Convert the postfix into Binary Expression Tree](https://www.krivalar.com/data-structures-expression-tree)
4. From expression tree, traverse and convert that into desired MongoDB query

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you're going for, but I'm assuming your SQL clause is going to be a string.

```js
let where = 'data = 3 AND ((d >= 4) OR (f < 5))';
let table_name = 'test_db';
let clause = `SELECT * from ${table_name} where ${where}`;
console.log(clause)
```

Comment: Basically I want to parse it and use as needed. I will update the SQL part to explain why I can't accept this answer